# Problem showing gujarati word in pdfsharp c#

Tags: c#, unicode, pdfsharp

I am trying to generate PDF document using pdfsharp with gujarati font (Noto Sans Gujarati - https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Gujarati/)

I am writing text "સભ્યના બિલ ઓર્ડર નંબરની વિગતો" but on pdf it is shown differently, here is image

[image]

But when you copy & paste that text to another editor like notepad++ than you will get the exact text "સભ્યના બિલ ઓર્ડર નંબરની વિગતો" - just showing incorrectly

Here is the code,

```
XFont font_400 = new XFont("Noto Sans Gujarati", 12, XFontStyle.Regular, new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode));

using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
{
   document.Info.Title = "My Gujarati Test Document";
   document.Info.Author = "snj886";

   PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
   page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;

   using (XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page))
   {
      gfx.MUH = PdfFontEncoding.Unicode;
      XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
      tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Left;
      tf.DrawString("સભ્યના બિલ ઓર્ડર નંબરની વિગતો", font_400, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(45, 45, page.Width - 90, 90), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
      gfx.DrawString("સભ્યના બિલ ઓર્ડર નંબરની વિગતો", font_400, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(45, 90, page.Width - 90, 90), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
   }

   document.Save("GujaratiTest.pdf");
   document.Close();
}
```

So, i think i am missing something to make it work correctly. please someone point me out.

thanks

Comment: The 2nd word બિલ is the following character sequence - `બ` (U+0AAC,  *Gujarati Letter Ba*) - િ (U+0ABF,  *Gujarati Vowel Sign I*) - `લ` (U+0AB2,  *Gujarati Letter La*). Unclear note about `*Gujarati Vowel Sign I*` **stands to the left of the consonant** at https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0abf/ or https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_0A80.html . Similarly the last word વિગતો containing *Gujarati Vowel Sign I*. Maybe a problem of rendering engine?

Comment: hmm, trying to figure this out by checking pdfsharp code. so, i make document using other framework and than compare it with the one generated by pdfsharp